# How to write custom authentication backend for one endpoint only (/metrics) in Django?

Tags: django, prometheus, django-authentication, django-middleware

I have a custom middleware in Django to force all the requests to go through a login authentication (with few exceptions like `api/token`).

This project allows users to authenticate either via a JWT token or a login in
`/admin/login` and all unauthenticated users are redirected to `/admin/login.` for authentication.

We deployed the project in Kubernetes and we want Prometheus to scrape `/metrics` endpoint but we don't want it to be exposed to unauthenticated users. Prometheus allows for authentication with `username` and `password`. The thing is that when a request is sent to `/metrics`, because of the middleware, the request is redirected to `/admin/login`.

So I believe I need to write a custom authentication backend specifically designed for the `metrics` endpoint and place it before the other authentication methods.

The request always goes through the middleware first so it will always be redirected to `/admin/login` and then will go through the authentication backend.

What is the right way of doing this?

- middleware.py

```py
class LoginRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        if path == '' or path == '/':
            return self.get_response(request)

        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
            # If the user is authenticated OR the URL is in the exempt list
            # go to the requested page
            return self.get_response(request)

        else:
            # Trying to access any page as a non authenticated user
            return redirect(f"{settings.LOGIN_URL}?next=/{path}")
```

- backends.py

```py
class MetricsAuthBackend(BaseBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        if '/metrics' in request.path:
            if username == "username":
                #need to fix this to use the hash of the password
                pwd_valid = check_password(password, "password")

                if pwd_valid:
                    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                    return user

        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```